# How to set <target> empty for not translated source in symfony?

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-3.1, jms-serializer

I am using JMS Translation bundle and localise.biz to translate. The problem I am facing is, when I extracting new translation keys from my code base and database, **I am expecting one of the below**:

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file source-language="en-US" target-language="bn" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="symfony" tool-name="Symfony"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" resname="">
        <source>badge.language</source>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file source-language="en-US" target-language="bn" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="symfony" tool-name="Symfony"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" resname="">
        <source>badge.language</source>
        <target state="new">badge.language</target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

**But what I am getting is this**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
      <file source-language="en-US" target-language="bn" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <header>
          <tool tool-id="symfony" tool-name="Symfony"/>
        </header>
        <body>
          <trans-unit id="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" resname="">
            <source>badge.language</source>
            <target>badge.language</target>
          </trans-unit>
        </body>
      </file>
    </xliff>
```

And the problem is when I am importing these into localise.biz, its considering that the translation is already done. I tried to google for the best approach but didn't find any helpful solution. Hope I will find something in here.

Thank you in advance. :)